# SQL Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, json, syntax-error

I want to return 10 json strings with mysql with data from my database, but i get the fallowing error: SQL Error (1172): Result consisted of more than one row!
yes i know the result consist in more rows, they are 10, the problem is how to print them all in different rows?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `search_for`(`value` TEXT)
    RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE sid TEXT;
    DECLARE semail TEXT;
    DECLARE sname TEXT;
    DECLARE slastname TEXT;
    DECLARE response TEXT;

    SELECT id,email,name,lastname INTO sid,semail,sname,slastname 
    FROM user WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
    OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
    OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') LIMIT 10;

    IF (semail IS NOT NULL) THEN             
        SET response = CONCAT('{"response":1,"id":',sid,',"email":"',semail,'","name":"',sname,'","lastname":"',slastname,'"}');
    ELSE
        SET response = CONCAT('{"response":0}');
    END IF;

    RETURN response;
END
```

after i use cursor and loop the method to get search result in multiple rows look like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ids TEXT;
    DECLARE response TEXT;
    DECLARE ids_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id,email,name,lastname  -- INTO ids,semail,sname,slastname 
        FROM user WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
        OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
        OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 2;

    OPEN ids_cursor;
    get_ids: LOOP

        FETCH ids_cursor INTO ids;

        IF finished = 2 THEN
            LEAVE get_ids;
        END IF;

        SET response = CONCAT(ids,";",response);

    END LOOP get_ids;
    CLOSE ids_cursor;

    RETURN response;
END
```

and i still get a little error (1328): Incorrect number of FETCH variables! why?

**Update**

edited next line:

`SELECT id --,email,name,lastname  -- INTO ids,semail,sname,slastname`

get a `NULL` response

Comment: You need to use a cursor and a loop.

Comment: I already tried once, but no success come out. now that i know for sure this is the answer i will try to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the end i will not use loop and cursor to reg response from this query, i will use a json string like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE response TEXT;

    SELECT CONCAT('{',GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ','),'}') INTO response
    FROM user 
    WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
       OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
       OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%');

    IF( response IS NOT NULL ) THEN
        RETURN response;
    ELSE
        RETURN CONCAT('{"response":0}');
    END IF;

END
```

i think sql cursor and loop's are for more advanced results, anyway work just finelike i did here, tcx!

Comment: i like `GROUP_CONCAT` function, it does do her work here in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Must not use function.
Maybe define view from this query ? Like this:

`create or replace view userquery select if(semail is not null,
CONCAT('{"response":1,"id":',sid,',"email":"',semail,'","name":"',sname,'","lastname":"',slastname,'"}'),"0") response,
    email,lastname,name FROM user ;`

And query

```
select response from userquery  where ...
```

Or simply use "if" in query, without function.

Comment: I want to use function, and already create view userquery in my function but i can not return a response from function so i change it a bit with `if else's` aaand now is fine i just return a sting of id-s, i think me going to post the answer here